# How to use D3's time scale in React (vanilla) with irregular data structure?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs

My goal is to create a multi-line graph (charting the amounts of a certain crime in a certain legislative district over time). The y-axis is the number of crimes, the x-axis is date (one week intervals), and each line represents a crime type.

The data is an array of objects and has already been filtered for a district and sorted by date:

```
[
  {
    count: "4",
    date: "2015-09-23",
    district: 12,
    to_timestamp: "2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    type: "MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT"
  },
  {
    count: "13",
    date: "2015-09-23",
    district: 12,
    to_timestamp: "2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    type: "BURGLARY"
  },
  ...
  {
    count: "3",
    date: "2016-03-23",
    district: 12,
    to_timestamp: "2016-03-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    type: "BURGLARY"
  }
]
```

My React components are as follows:

```
const Line = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    path:         React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    stroke:       React.PropTypes.string,
    fill:         React.PropTypes.string,
    strokeWidth:  React.PropTypes.number
  },

  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      stroke:       'blue',
      fill:         'none',
      strokeWidth:  3
    };
  },

  render() {
    let { path, stroke, fill, strokeWidth } = this.props;
    return (
      <path
        d={path}
        fill={fill}
        stroke={stroke}
        strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
        />
    );
  }

});

const DataSeries = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    colors:             React.PropTypes.func,
    data:               React.PropTypes.array,
    interpolationType:  React.PropTypes.string,
    xScale:             React.PropTypes.func,
    yScale:             React.PropTypes.func
  },

  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      data:               [],
      interpolationType:  'basis',
      colors:             d3.scale.category10()
    };
  },

  render() {
    let { data, colors, xScale, yScale, interpolationType } = this.props;

    let line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate(interpolationType)
      .x((d) => { return xScale(d.to_timestamp); })
      .y((d) => { return yScale(d.count); });

    let dataGroup = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.type;
      })
      .entries(data);

    let lines = dataGroup.map((series, id) => {
      return (
        <Line
          path={line(series.values)}
          stroke={colors(id)}
          key={id}
          />
      );
    });

    return (
      <g>
        <g>{lines}</g>
      </g>
    );
  }

});

const LineChart = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    width:  React.PropTypes.number,
    height: React.PropTypes.number,
    data:   React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
  },

  getDefaultProps(){
    return {
      width:  600,
      height: 300
    }
  },

  render() {
    let { width, height, data } = this.props;

    let xScale = d3.time.scale()
                    .domain([new Date('2015-09-24T00:00:00.000Z'), new Date('2016-03-24T00:00:00.000Z')])
                    .range([0, width]);

    let yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) {
                        return d.count;
                      }), d3.max(data, function(d) {
                        return d.count;
                      })])
                    .range([height, 10]);

    console.log(data);

    return (
      <svg width={width} height={height}>
          <DataSeries
            xScale={xScale}
            yScale={yScale}
            data={data}
            width={width}
            height={height}
            />
      </svg>
    );
  }

});
```

I believe the problem is with `xScale` and `yScale` variables on the `LineChart` component. To start, I hardcoded the first and last dates rather than using `x.min()` and `y.min()`, but neither way is working.

An extra issue is that there may not necessarily be a data point for a given crime on a given date; that is, there are no data points that explicitly register `count: 0`. There error I am receiving is:

`Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,191.25LNaN,1…".`

For reference, I've been following these two guides:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-multi-line-chart-using-d3js--cms-22935
http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/04/using-d3-js-with-react-js.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time scale needs date objects while you're providing a string representations of dates.

Try this:

```
let line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate(interpolationType)
    .x((d) => { return xScale(new Date(d.to_timestamp)); })
    .y((d) => { return yScale(d.count); });
```

Or better transoform your data:

```
data.forEach(d => d.to_timestamp = new Date(d.to_timestamp));
```

Comment: Any thoughts on adding axes?